# Entity Framework locking database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

The query below is very slow and inefficient. Depending on the user supplied parameters, it could take a minute to run. We can obviously make the query more efficient, but our issue is that when it's run, it seems to lock the database.

On our clients site, when it's run, our application will hang on every pc on our clients site until it completes. If we run the same query in management studio, it still takes about a minute to run, but it doesn't affect any other pc terminals..i.e. the database doesn't lock.

Does anybody have any ideas as to why this is happening through EF? (we're using EF6)

Edit: Just to reiterate - Our issue isn't about improving the query (we can do that)..It's why this query locks the database when run through the entity framework (affecting every instance of our application running on our clients site), and doesn't affect any when run through management studio.

```
var details =
                        (from stock in
                             entities.StockTransactions.Where(x => x.Deleted == null 
                                                                   && x.NouTransactionTypeID == NouvemGlobal.TransactionTypeGoodsReceiptId
                                                                   && x.IsBox == true)
                         join attribute in entities.Attributes.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.GradingDate) >= start &&
                                                             DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.GradingDate) <= end && x.NouDocStatusID != status) on stock.AttributeID equals attribute.AttributeID
                         join intakeDetail in entities.APGoodsReceiptDetails on stock.MasterTableID equals intakeDetail.APGoodsReceiptDetailID
                         join intake in entities.APGoodsReceipts on intakeDetail.APGoodsReceiptID equals intake.APGoodsReceiptID
                         select new StockDetail
                         {
                             LoadingStockDetail = true,
                             Paid = stock.KillPaymentItems.Any(pay => pay.Deleted == null),
                             StockTransactionID = stock.StockTransactionID,
                             APGoodsReceiptDetailID = stock.MasterTableID,
                             AttributeID = attribute.AttributeID,
                             TransactionWeight = stock.TransactionWeight,
                             Serial = stock.Serial,
                             TransactionDate = stock.TransactionDate,
                             Detained = attribute.Detained,
                             Condemned = attribute.Condemned,
                             Eartag = attribute.Eartag,
                             KillType = attribute.KillType,
                             NouDocStatusID = attribute.NouDocStatusID,
                             Breed = attribute.NouBreed,
                             Grade = attribute.Grade,
                             DOB = attribute.DOB,
                             Identigen = attribute.Identigen,
                             HoldingNumber = attribute.HoldingNumber,
                             CountryOfOrigin = attribute.CountryOfOrigin,
                             KillNumber = attribute.KillNumber,
                             Generic1 = attribute.Generic1,
                             CarcassNumber = attribute.CarcassNumber,
                             CarcassSide = attribute.CarcassSide == 1 ? StockDetail.Side.Side1 : StockDetail.Side.Side2,
                             AgeInMonths = attribute.AgeInMonths,
                             AgeInDays = attribute.AgeInDays,
                             Cleanliness = attribute.NouCleanliness,
                             SequencedDate = attribute.SequencedDate,
                             Category = attribute.NouCategory,
                             Sex = attribute.Sex,
                             GradingDate = attribute.GradingDate,
                             CustomerID = attribute.Customer,
                             FarmAssured = attribute.FarmAssured,
                             Clipped = attribute.Clipped,
                             Casualty = attribute.Casualty,
                             Lame = attribute.Lame,
                             IsFullCarcass = stock.IsBox,
                             NumberOfMoves = attribute.NoOfMoves,
                             PreviousResidency = attribute.PreviousResidency,
                             TotalResidency = attribute.TotalResidency,
                             CurrentResidency = attribute.CurrentResidency,
                             DateOfLastMove = attribute.DateOfLastMove,
                             Imported = attribute.Imported,
                             PaidWeight = attribute.ColdWeight,
                             UTM = attribute.AgeInMonths != null && attribute.AgeInMonths <= ApplicationSettings.GraderLabelUOMAge ? 1 : 0,
                             OTM = attribute.AgeInMonths != null && attribute.AgeInMonths > ApplicationSettings.GraderLabelUOMAge ? 1 : 0,
                             SupplierID = intake.BPMasterID_Supplier
                         })
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: Use SQL profilter to see what query entity framework generates. Run that query in Microsoft SQL management studio and see what indexes are missing to improve performance. SELECT statement don't normally block sql, only for example if you use like MySQL [SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html]). To see if database is locked, try opening addional Visual Studio which connect to database and execute some simple query while upper query is executing.

Comment: From the looks of things, this will cause table scans on a lot of tables (doesn't this create a `CROSS JOIN` statement?). Regarding the database locking issue, where is this piece of code run? On a server somewhere the clients connect to (e.g. a WCF service or ASP.Net page?) or does each client run their own query? If this is run a a server, and a lot of rows are returned, I can imagine this will lock the server for over a minute.

Comment: It's not the query performance that is our concern (the query has been changed and is now performing fine). Our concern is the apparent locking of the db when this query was run from the EF. We don't understand why an inefficient select query run from the EF locks the db, while the same query doesn't lock the db when ran through SSMS